# Restructuring html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have the following HTML element structure:

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="keyword">belal</span>
    <span class="string"> "Belal Mostafa"</span>
</span>
```

now I want to dynamically select the `.parent` class and restructure its children it to look like:

```
<span class="parent">
    <span class="keyword">belal</span>
    <span class="string"> "Belal </span>
    <span class="string"> Mostafa"</span>
</span>
```

I was thinking of the following but still can't get it done:

- unwrap .string class get the text from it
- then split it on white spaces
- then append each string to a new span element

Comment: "Still can't get it done"—so, what have you tried? Can you show us the jQuery code that you have attempted?

Comment: I am able to append a span inside the .string class , but I don't know how to close the first .string class after "belal first then open a new tag for the other word Mostafa" , do you get my point ?

Comment: @BelalMostafaAmin you can *remove* the first one and replace it with all the parts (rather than try to "close" it after the first part then add additional parts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop on each `.parent`, after that loop on each string and split all white space and append the result to the parent.

Example

```js
$(".parent .string").each(function(){
  if($(this).text().trim().indexOf(" ") != -1)
  {
    var parent = $(this).parents(".parent");
    $.each($(this).text().trim().split(" "),function(index,value){
      parent.append("<span class='string'>"+value+"</span>");
    });
    $(this).remove();
  }
});
```

```css
.string{
  border:solid 1px #888;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="parent">
    <span class="keyword">belal</span>
    <span class="string"> "Belal Mostafa Test"</span>
</span>
```

Comment: great, this is working, i can't add the right solution for some reason but it is working as wanted

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with jQuery `append`

```js
var text  = $(".string").text().trim(); //getting text of string element
$(".string").remove(); //removing existing
text.split(" ").forEach(function(item){ //splitting it to append span elements
  $(".parent").append("<span class='string'>" + item + "</span>"); //appending to parent element
});
```

```css
.string{
  border: 1px solid blue; /*just for view, remove it later*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="parent">
    <span class="keyword">belal</span>
    <span class="string"> "Belal Mostafa"</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Append your span in the parent element not in the .keyword span ;p

Comment: Ohh sorry, overlook, I'll fix it :)

Comment: Other tip, use trim() method to avoid space before and after the text. Here you create an empty span